# How do I add a new line in a react usestate string

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-hooks, use-state

Currently my code is something like this:

```html
const [simulationResult, setSimulationResult] = useState("");

let simulationFormatedString = "one /n two";
setSimulationResult(simulationFormatedString);

<div>
{simulationResult}
</div>
```

**I want to show the result as:
one
two**

**instead of:**

**one**

**two**

Comment: is it displaying in HTML? not pre-formatted styled? use `<br>` in that case. also, `/n` should be `\n`

Comment: This code, as-is, would result in an infinite re-render loop.  Because the act of rendering the component updates the state, which triggers a re-render.  Is that the problem you're observing?

Comment: Hello no, right now its not displaying in HTML, and the trigger for the function that renders this is an onClick so the infinite render loop is not being observed

Answer (score 0):

as @dandavis said, line break is `\n` not `/n`

Then, you can remove it by replacing it with zero space `""`

```
const [simulationResult, setSimulationResult] = useState("");

const simulationFormatedString = "one \n two";
const finalSimulationString = simulationFormatedString.replace(/\r?\n|\r/g, "");
setSimulationResult(<span>{finalSimulationString}</span>);

<div>
{simulationResult}
</div>
```